# Generics Type paramenter depends on itself

Tags: java, generics

I came across with following:

I understand this :

*In a class's type parameter section, a type variable T directly depends on a type variable S if S is the bound of T, while T depends on S if either T directly depends on S or T directly depends on a type variable U that depends on S (using this definition recursively)*.

But

**It is a compile-time error if a type variable in a class's type parameter section depends on itself.**

what does it mean ?
[Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2)

Comment: this is not allowed **T extends T**?

Comment: @Eugene Yup. That's what my answer says. I guess you missed it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What the statement means is that a type parameter variable cannot depend on itself. The following code is not allowed :

```
class Generic<T extends T> {

}
```

Here `T` is a type-parameter variable and it cannot depend on itself (directly or inderictly). On the other hand, the following code is allowed :

```
public class GenericRecursive<T extends GenericRecursive<T>> {

}
```

Comment: Well as far as I know as a type parameter is supertype and subtype of itself. I may be wrong

Comment: @CKing I did miss it. 1+

Comment: @Mukeshkumarsaini Regardless of whether it is a subtype of itself or not, what good is the statement `T extends T` since we know that all objects will always pass the *IS-A* test with themselves.

Comment: @Cking : is it recursive means S depends on T , T depends on U and U depends on S again ?

Comment: Yes, that wouldn't be allowed as it would be recursive. But that is not what the section is talking about. It is specifically talking about a type variable depending on **itself**. (Here *itself* refers to one single type variable and not more than one)

Answer (score 2):

> It is a compile-time error if a type variable in a class's type
>   parameter section depends on itself.

The parameter cannot derives from itself.

For example it is not legal :

```
class YourClass<S extends S> { 
}
```

But you probably will not use this as it makes no really sense.

You could do that for example :

```
class YourClass<T extends S, S extends T> { 
}
```

And it will not compile too because `T` depends on `S` that depends on itself (cycle)

Comment: `class YourClass<T extends String, String extends T>`??. Also, the section specifically talks about type parameter variables depending on themselves and not on other type parameters.

Comment: @CKing If the parameter depends on something that depends on the parameter. Finally what does it mean ? It means that the parameter depends on itself. It is the cycle principle

Comment: Fair enough; however, it all boils down to the type parameter depending on itself (directly or indirectly)

Comment: @CKing Thank your for acknowledging it :)